# htaccess RewriteRule URL's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use htaccess to rewrite my URL's so here is what I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+),([a-z0-9._.-]+),([^-]+) index.php?go=$1&lang=$2 [L]
```

and code PHP:

```
function rewrite_seo($id, $title, $langs) {
    global $core;
    if($core->getSettings('seof')) {
        $result = $id.','.$langs.','.changeSigns($title).'';
    } else $result = '?go='.$id.'&lang='.$langs;
    return $result;
}
```

My URLs look like:

```
http://localhost/script/12,en,home
```

but want to look like this:

```
http://localhost/script/en/home,12
```

how to modify this code?

Answer (score 0):

> localhost/script/12,en,home TO
>   localhost/script/en/home,12

Did u try to modify line 4?

Put that:
`$result = $langs.'/'.changeSigns($title).','.$id;`

Please take a look to PHP.net webpage http://php.net/manual/de/internals2.opcodes.concat.php

Comment: yes but I have a 404 error because I have to modify the httacces but I can not.

Comment: So, post wich htaccess rule do u have or try change according to that :D new rules.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the links written in PHP as pointed out in the previous answer :

```
$result = $langs.'/'.changeSigns($title).','.$id;
```

And then change the matching rule in your htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9._.-]+)\/([^-]+),([^-]+) index.php?go=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

Even better, you can make more specific capture regex, so it would be easier to read and understand :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+),([^-]+) index.php?go=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```